# How to list an array of TabView items in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I have a project where parts of `ContentView` is supposed to change when different tabs are selected. I have the following struct and the array for the TabView items:

```swift
struct TabItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: Text
    var image: Image
    var tag: Int
}

let tabData = [
    TabItem(title: Text("Tab 1"), image: Image(systemName: "1"), tag: 1),
    TabItem(title: Text("Tab 2"), image: Image(systemName: "2"), tag: 2),
    TabItem(title: Text("Tab 3"), image: Image(systemName: "3"), tag: 3),
    TabItem(title: Text("Tab 4"), image: Image(systemName: "4"), tag: 4)
]
```

I am trying to list these inside `TabView` but couldn't figure out how to do so. Tried below approach, but having no luck so far.

```swift
TabView {
    ContentView()
        .tabItem {
        // code goes here...
        }.tag // tag goes here
}
```

I am aware that I can also use the `TabView(selection: )` with an `@State` variable, but I am also not sure how to implement that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TabView can be displayed as below (attribute `selectedTab` keeps track of the tab that is selected by the user) :

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let tabData = [
        TabItem(title: Text("Tab 1"), image: Image(systemName: "1"), tag: 1),
        TabItem(title: Text("Tab 2"), image: Image(systemName: "2"), tag: 2),
        TabItem(title: Text("Tab 3"), image: Image(systemName: "3"), tag: 3),
        TabItem(title: Text("Tab 4"), image: Image(systemName: "4"), tag: 4)
    ]

    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {

            ForEach(tabData) { tabItem in
                Text("Screen: \(tabItem.tag)")
                    .tabItem {
                        tabItem.title
                        tabItem.image
                }.tag(tabItem.tag)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct TabItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: Text
    var image: Image
    var tag: Int
}
```

Comment: you can remove tag in your model and use id as a "tag".

Comment: @BabakHSL As long as it is `Hashable`, we can use that.  I used here for ease of reference so that we know what is being referred.